# How to fix Raspberry Pi TensorFlow Hadoop error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

2022-09-01 11:56:43.299533: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the file or directory does not exist.